# Loading arrays through select2 with text containing HTML-entities are not showing as the special characters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select style="width: 50%" id="div">

        </select>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

and in javascript:

```
$('select').select2(); 



array =
[
    { id: 0, text: "&mu;" },
    { id: 1, text: "&cent;" },
];

$("#div").select2({ data: array })
```

The result will be a select with option `"& m u ; "` and `"& c e n t;"` and not `"&mu;"` and `"&cent;"`. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You're passing html into the text option, which is why it's not matching how you were expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

I see

```
array = [
{ id: 0, text: "&mu;" },
{ id: 1, text: "&cent;" },];
```

You have no problems with the coding?
An example of working with symbols - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXomLP

Comment: It seems to work by just putting μ into the code, but shouldnt you be using this: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html